# TabNavigator - React Native Android

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

Is there any way by which we can show the tabs to navigate screen in bottom part rather than default top part in Android. I am making an app where I need tabs to be at bottom just like in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that by simply adding "tabBarPosition: 'bottom' " to TabBarConfig, I was able to get the expected output. You can refer to the docs [here.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#API-Definition)